# Exclude last columns while export to pdf - Angular 6 Kendo

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, export-to-pdf

i am trying to exclude last column while exporting grid to pdf.

This is my pdf export component that i am using it in different components.
This app kendo pdf component

```
<kendo-grid-pdf fileName="{{pdfname}}" [allPages]="true" paperSize="A4" [repeatHeaders]="true" [landscape]="true" >
  <kendo-grid-pdf-margin top="2cm" left="1cm" right="1cm" bottom="2cm"></kendo-grid-pdf-margin>
  <ng-template kendoGridPDFTemplate let-pageNum="pageNum" let-totalPages="totalPages">
   <div class="page-template">
      <div class="header">
        <div style="float: right">Page {{ pageNum }} of {{ totalPages }}</div>
       {{componentName}}
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        Page {{ pageNum }} of {{ totalPages }}
      </div>
    </div>

  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-pdf>
<kendo-grid-excel fileName="{{pdfname}}"></kendo-grid-excel>
```

This a grid that i want to export :

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="409" [pageSize]="state.take"
[skip]="state.skip"
[sort]="state.sort"
[filter]="state.filter"
[sortable]="true"
[pageable]="true"
[filterable]="true"
(dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)">
<ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
  <button class="kendo-pdf" kendoGridPDFCommand icon="file-pdf">Export to PDF</button>
  <button class="kendo-excel" type="button" kendoGridExcelCommand icon="file-excel">Export to Excel</button>
</ng-template>
  <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="Name" width="50" filter="text" format="{0:c}">
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="age" title="Age" width="50" filter="numeric" format="{0:c}">
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="city" title="City" width="50">
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column width="20" field="Edit / Delete" filter="false">
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem  >
        <a (click)="showConfirmation()"> <i class="fa fa-trash" ></i></a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/addEmployee']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active"  > <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
      </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>  
  <app-kendoPDF [componentName]=name></app-kendoPDF>
```

I want to exclude edit/delete field while exporting

**Edit : This what i tried but didn't work**

in order components :

```
kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="409" [pageSize]="state.take" [skip]="state.skip" [sort]="state.sort" [filter]="state.filter"
  [sortable]="true" [pageable]="true" [filterable]="true" (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)">
  <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <button  class="kendo-pdf" kendoGridPDFCommand icon="file-pdf">Export to PDF</button>
    <button class="kendo-excel" type="button" kendoGridExcelCommand icon="file-excel">Export to Excel</button>
  </ng-template>
  <kendo-grid-column field="orderNumber" title="Order Number" width="20" filter="text">
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="orderTable" title="Order Table" width="20" filter="text" format="{0:c}">
  </kendo-grid-column>
<app-kendoPDF [componentName]=name>
    <kendo-grid-column field="orderNumber" title="Order Number">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="orderTable" title="Order Table">
    </kendo-grid-column>
</app-kendoPDF>
</kendo-grid>
```

KendoPdf Component :

```
<kendo-grid-pdf fileName="{{pdfname}}" [allPages]="true" paperSize="A4" [repeatHeaders]="true" [landscape]="true" >
  <kendo-grid-pdf-margin top="2cm" left="1cm" right="1cm" bottom="2cm"></kendo-grid-pdf-margin>
  <ng-template kendoGridPDFTemplate let-pageNum="pageNum" let-totalPages="totalPages">
   <div class="page-template">
      <div class="header">
        <div style="float: right">Page {{ pageNum }} of {{ totalPages }}</div>
       {{componentName}}
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        Page {{ pageNum }} of {{ totalPages }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</kendo-grid-pdf>
<kendo-grid-excel fileName="{{pdfname}}"></kendo-grid-excel>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: printed all the grid instead of specific column

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `kendo-grid-column` components  inside your `kendo-grid-pdf` component, like this:

```
<kendo-grid-pdf
    fileName="ProductsPrice.pdf"
    paperSize="A4"
    [scale]="0.8"
    [repeatHeaders]="true"
    [margin]="{ top: '1cm', left: '1cm', right: '1cm', bottom: '1cm' }">
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Price">
        </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid-pdf>
```

Place a `kendo-grid-column` component for each column you want to appear in the PDF.

Since you use the same PDF export component in multiple places and the columns change in each case, you can customize the columns for each case using the `ng-content` tag.

To do this, add `<ng-content></ng-content>` inside the `kendo-grid-pdf` component that's inside the `app-kendoPDF` component and put the `kendo-grid-column` components, when you need them, in the template of the component that uses the `app-kendoPDF` component, like this:

In the `app-kendoPDF` component's template:

```
<kendo-grid-pdf fileName="{{pdfname}}" [allPages]="true" paperSize="A4" [repeatHeaders]="true" [landscape]="true" >
    <kendo-grid-pdf-margin top="2cm" left="1cm" right="1cm" bottom="2cm"></kendo-grid-pdf-margin>
    <ng-template kendoGridPDFTemplate let-pageNum="pageNum" let-totalPages="totalPages">
        <div class="page-template">
            <div class="header">
                <div style="float: right">Page {{ pageNum }} of {{ totalPages }}</div>
                {{componentName}}
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                Page {{ pageNum }} of {{ totalPages }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <!--Add this to have the kendo-grid-column components from the code below appear here-->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</kendo-grid-pdf>
<kendo-grid-excel fileName="{{pdfname}}"></kendo-grid-excel>
```

In the second template you included, instead of simply `<app-kendoPDF [componentName]=name></app-kendoPDF>`:

```
<app-kendoPDF [componentName]=name>
    <kendo-grid-column field="<name of column #1>" title="<name of column #1>">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="<name of column #2>" title="<name of column #2>">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="<name of column #3>" title="<name of column #3>">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <!--And so on...-->
</app-kendoPDF>
```

You can read more about the PDF export in the Kendo documentation [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/pdf-export/#toc-customizing-exported-columns).

Comment: sorry man but i didn't understand what you are trying to say .

Comment: You didn't understand anything at all? Basically there are two things to understand here. One is the use of the `kendo-grid-column` and the other is the use of `ng-content`. I've edited the code a bit to perhaps make it clearer.

Comment: man didn't worked with me . I tried what answered but nothing worked

Comment: What happened? Did you get any exceptions? Did the page load at all?

Comment: I've edited the answer again, see if it's clearer now. Did you copy the code from the answer exactly as I've written it or did you change the column names to fit yours?

Comment: recheck my question please . i did what you have said but didn't work

Comment: What if my columns are created dynamically (I don't know their field name)?

Comment: How do you know which columns you want to export and which columns you don't? If you have an array of column objects and each object has a property that says if that column gets exported, you can use `*ngFor` to create `ng-template` elements inside `app-kendoPDF` with an `*ngIf` directive that checks the property I mentioned in order to decide whether to place the `kendo-grid-column` element inside the `ng-template`. You still have to use some field name to connect your dynamically created DataSource to the columns. I hope it's clear enough.